# Installing a new environment SharePoint 2016 on my company

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, installation, windows-server

I need to install a new server in my company, which is configured with Windows Server 2016 and other Microsoft products (SQL Server - Active Directory - Microsoft SharePoint 2016),

my question is:
There is some tool or software, that allows me to specify the characteristics of Microsoft that I want to install and that tells me what are the minimum resources that my server must have for an optimal performance

Answer (score 2):

**As per your description,** you are trying to build a **Single-Server** farm that uses SQL Server on the same server. plus you need to install AD on the same farm.

**Initially,** this topology will work but it's heavily recommended to isolate the AD from the SharePoint farm even if it's `Single-Server` farm to avoid the performance issue.

**Additionally,**, the `Single-Server` farm with AD installed [is **not** supported in production environments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2764086/certain-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-installation-scenarios-are-no), and generally, the `Single-Server` farm should be used for development and learning purpose!

---

**Regarding the minimum requirement,**

You can get all details at [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

And based on the above link, the minimum hardware specification for `Single-Server` farm are :

- **RAM:** 16 GB.
- **Processor:** 64-bit, 4 cores.
- **Harddisk space:** 80 GB for system drive, 100 GB for the second drive.

It's the minimum hardware specification, you can **scale it up** as you prefer based on your budget/requirements and actually, this is will lead to good performance.

---

**Regarding the tools,**

I don't think there is a tool to architect your farm and suggest the minimum requirements because it will depend on a lot of different factors and differ from farm to farm and client requirements to other and this is the main job of your SharePoint architect,

Based on my humble knowledge, the currently available tools for measuring the performance and perform Performance test.

Meanwhile, I don't think you will need an independent tool to specify the minimum resources for a single-server farm where you can follow what I have mentioned in the above second section.